# Simplify sort of Excel cell names in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I am learning python and am having trouble with sorting. I feel like the key (for sorting) is too limiting and difficult to use once sorting algorithm begins getting more complicated. Here is the list I want to sort:

```
['A1', 'AA1', 'B3', 'B2', 'BB1', 'AZ15']
```

where each value is like an excel column (ie. `'BB1' > 'AZ15' > 'AA1' > 'B3' > 'B2' > 'A1'`).

Here is the solution I came up with after reading the following [guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html).

```
def cmp_cell_ids(name1, name2):
    def split(name):
        letter = ''
        number = ''
        for ch in name:
            if ch in '1234567890':
                number += ch
            else:
                letter += ch
        return letter, int(number)
    ltr1, num1 = split(name1)
    ltr2, num2 = split(name2)
    if len(ltr1) == len(ltr2):
        if ltr1 == ltr2:
            return num1 > num2
        else:
            return ltr1 > ltr2
    return len(ltr1) > len(ltr2)

def cmp_to_key(mycmp):
    class K:
        def __init__(self, obj, *args):
            self.obj = obj
        def __lt__(self, other):
            return not mycmp(self.obj, other.obj)
        def __gt__(self, other):
            return mycmp(self.obj, other.obj)
        def __eq__(self, other):
            return self.obj == other.obj
        def __le__(self, other):
            if self.__eq__(other):
                return True
            return self.__lt__(other)
        def __ge__(self, other):
            if self.__eq__(other):
                return True
            return self.__gt__(other)
        def __ne__(self, other):
            return self.obj != other.obj
    return K

key_cell_ids_cmp = cmp_to_key(cmp_cell_ids)
cell_ids = ['A1','AA1','B3','B2','BB1','AZ15']
cell_ids.sort(key=key_cell_ids_cmp)
print(cell_ids)
```

Which gives the desired output

```
['A1', 'B2', 'B3', 'AA1', 'AZ15', 'BB1']
```

I am wondering if there is any easier/more pythonic implementation to this (in particular, I would love if I could get rid of that wrapper class).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, writing (or copy-pasting) a `cmp_to_key` function is unnecessary. Just use the one in `itertools`.

In this case, though, it would be a lot more natural to use a key! Just split each element into a tuple of row name length (so `B` is before `AA`), a string row, and an integer column, and rely on the natural lexicographic ordering of tuples.

Viz:

```
import re

def cell_key(cell):
    m = re.match("([A-Z]+)(\\d+)", cell)
    return (len(m.group(1)), m.group(1), int(m.group(2)))

cells = ['A1', 'AA1', 'B3', 'B2', 'BB1', 'AZ15']

print(sorted(cells, key=cell_key))
```

Comment: What kind of a Python-3 version you're using? because not the `m[1]` which is indexing a match object, nor sorting heterogeneous data is possible in Python-3.

Comment: @Kasramvd 3.6, since you asked, which was when `Match` got a `__getitem__` method. As for "sorting heterogeneous data", I'm not sure what you mean. All keys are `int,str,int` tuples, being compared in the normal way.

Comment: @Kasramvd If you'd like to see how tuple comparison works, try doing `('A', 2) < ('B', 1)`. (That should work in any version of python, not just 3.6 or later.)

Comment: Instead of `(len(m[1]), m[1], int(m[2]))`, you could also use `(int(m[1], 36), int(m[2]))`, i.e. treat the first part as a number base 36 (digits 0-9 are not used, but that does not hurt sorting).

Comment: I've lost keep tracking of minor changes in latest versions but In Python-3.7 I get both `TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()` and `TypeError: '_sre.SRE_Match' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @Kasramvd Yeah, as I said you'll need python 3.6 for the getitem method. Or just change `m[1]` to `m.group(1)` and similarly for `m[2]`.

Comment: @Kasramvd as for the "unorderable types" error, I have no idea how you got that. Are you sure you copied the code correctly?

Comment: Wow, I'm glad I asked this question. I didn't know about this re package before. I also learned about tuple comparison from your comments. Thanks!

Comment: @Sneftel Yes it doesn't return "unorderable types" error but I got the same with my code that the key function returns the same result except that all the characters are separated and just the last item is int. `def keyfunc(arg):
    ...:     *m, last = re.findall(r'[a-z]|\d+$', arg, re.I)
    ...:     return (*m, int(last))`

Comment: That's because the `sorted` function tries to compare the items individually but if you compare two lists or tuples with different datatypes inside them it works fine. But it's strange how it works well with your key-function.

Comment: @Kasramvd Comparing tuples only makes sense when there's a 1-to-1 correspondence between the elements. That is, you should not compare "variable length" tuples.

Comment: @Sneftel But `('A', 'A', 1) > ('B', 3)` works well. However it does seem that `sorted`  zips the tuples when you use a custom key.

Comment: @Kasramvd `('A', 'A', 1) > ('B', 3)` works because the comparison is already decided after the first element, so it never has to compare the second `'A'` to `3`.

Answer (score 3):

Very similar solution to @Sneftel's, but I approached the problem by finding the index of the first numeric character.

```
import re

A = ['A1', 'AA1', 'B3', 'B2', 'BB1', 'AZ15']

def sorter(x):
    n = re.search('\d', x).start()
    return (len(x[:n]), x[:n], int(x[n:]))

res = sorted(A, key=sorter)

print(res)

['A1', 'B2', 'B3', 'AA1', 'AZ15', 'BB1']
```